# Is Dismissible only used for deleting?

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView.builder` which display a bunch of tasks added by the user. I want to mark the task as done when swiping from left and delete the task when swiping from right. I initially started with `Dismissible` since it can display sperarate result depending on the swiping direction, but am unsure on whether it can only delete regardless of swiping direction.

Can i implement the delete and mark complete functionality using `Dismissible` or would i have to use another widget to make this happen?

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: Itemlist.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                            String item = Itemlist[index].toString();
                          return Dismissible(
                              key: Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
                              onDismissed: (direction){
                                setState((){
                                    deleteItem(Itemlist[index].id, index);
                                  }
                                );
                              },
                              background: Container(
                                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                color: Colors.red,
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                            secondaryBackground: Container(
                              child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                              color: Colors.green,
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            ),
                              child: Itemlist[index],
                            );
                          }
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: `Dismissible` is designed only for the purpose of deletion, if you want to do something else, you can either override this widget or create your own custom widget using `GestureDetector`, `Stack` and `Positioned`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
onDismissed: (direction) {
  print(direction.index);
  if(direction.index==2)
  {
    anythingWhatYouWant();
  }
  else
  {
    deleteFunction();
  }
},
```